# Transforming vertical Data to a horizontal format in R

Tags: r

This is a conceptual question.  I have data in a SQL Express database that I am loading into R via the ODBC package.  The data format is:

name, symbol, number of days from 1/1/2015, closing price.

```
The main company, tmc, 1, 12
The xyz company, xyz, 1, 233
The one company, toc, 1, 56
The two company, ttc, 1, 88

The main company,tmc, 2, 11.5
The xyz company, xyz, 2, 232
The one Company, toc, 2, 59
The two company, ttc, 2, 89
```

My question is: is there a R package that can transform the data from being in a vertical format to horizontal?  ie

name, symbol, Price **Lag1**, Price **Lag2**

```
The main company, tmc, 12, 11.5
The xyz company, xyz, 233, 232
The one company, toc, 56,59
The two company, ttc, 88,89
```

Or should i try to do this with SQL code?

Answer (score 4):

We could use `dcast` from `reshape2` or `spread` from `tidyr`.  Before reshaping, it may be better to change the lengthy column names with spaces to no space column names.  We specify the value column in `value.var` in `dcast`.

```
library(reshape2)
colnames(df1)[3:4] <- c('numberofdays', 'closing_price')
dcast(df1, name+symbol~paste0('Lag', numberofdays), 
                  value.var='closing_price')
#              name symbol Lag1  Lag2
#1 The main company    tmc   12  11.5
#2  The one company    toc   56  59.0
#3  The two company    ttc   88  89.0
#4  The xyz company    xyz  233 232.0
```

---

A similar option using `dplyr/tidyr` would be to `mutate` the 'numberofdays' by `paste`ing the 'Lag' string and convert the 'long' format to 'wide' with `spread.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(numberofdays=paste0('Lag', numberofdays)) %>%
    spread(numberofdays, closing_price)
```

Comment: Great..after using the above code, I will have lag values that start from 1 and end around 3000.  Is there a R package that can convert the closing price lag data to percentage changes from the prior day? ie R package quantmod..is a guess

Comment: @RStudio2015 Thanks.  Sorry, didn't really get your question.  It is better you post that as a separate one.

Comment: Ok I will research and post it if necessary